# Rails 6.1 multiple read replicas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, database-replication

Our Rails app has some operations with very high database load on Postgres views, which we would like to spread out across multiple replicas. [The docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html) initially suggest that any given model can only have a `reading` and a `writing` database, but then another section discusses [balancing replicas](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#load-balancing-replicas), suggesting there is support for this.

I can see that I might be able to achieve this with different abstract ActiveRecord models pointing to different replicas in their `reading` roles, but I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :read_replica_3) do
  # Do something
end
```

Can I achieve this in Rails 6.1?

Answer (score 0):

There are guides for each minor rails version that [you can select at the top of the Guides homepage](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/)... and it's then easy to see the guide for the feature you're interested in if it's supported in that version (and if a guide has been written for it).  [As you can see](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/active_record_multiple_databases.html), there's good support for replica definition/switching in 6.1, including the `connected_to role: :the_role` feature.

Worth adding that [the same feature exists in the API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/), although I'm not sure if there's a page linking to all the other versions - I just alter the URL manually in my browser.